# -bash: PATH: command not found displayed when terminal is launched

Tags: node.js, bash, terminal

I'm not sure where to start on this and hope someone can help solve this issue.

I was having permission issues with Node.js so I decided to completely uninstall node by throwing a bunch of commands found online into terminal. And also accessing /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include to delete the folders manually. As you can see, I really wanted to uninstall Node and had no clue what I was doing.

Now when I launch terminal, "-bash: PATH: command not found" is displayed. And I can't install node via NVM.

How can I fix this problem?

edit:

.bash_profile shows

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #    Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

and .baschrc shows

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export NVM_DIR="/Users/colette/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Comment: Peruse your `.bashrc`. My proverbial money is on there being a line like `PATH = ...` in there (which should, of course, be `PATH=...`).

Comment: How do I access .bashrc?

Comment: Open it in your favourite editor...?

Comment: this is what I found, export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export NVM_DIR="/Users/colette/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

Comment: Hmm. Maybe check `.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`?

Comment: This is from .bash_profile, ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Comment: @heydeer A bit hard to read without line breaks, but is that a lonely `PATH` in there?

Comment: @heydeer And there we go. What's that fourth line supposed to do?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. But there's only a single space in my text edit file. Seems to have been a mistake when I copy and paste it on stackoverflow. The actual file reads (PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/l...)

Comment: @heydeer Either one is just nonsensical anyway, so you'd probably better remove it (or at least comment it out).

Comment: I did comment it out and it did the trick, thanks. Not sure how that line happened or what it means.